# R Piecewise Growth Regression, lmer()

Tags: r, lme4, lmer

I would like to do a **piecewise growth regression** with my data, based on Raudenbush/Bryk(1992/2002), Hierarchical Linear Models, p178 - 179.

I will have to apply a Multi level Model to do this.

I is the lme4-package I will need to use.

My data contains sales revenues over time per ID. 
I have two breakpoints: sales>10 and sales>25.
I want to analyse the growth in sales before and after the breakpoints.

I have two variables for every ID:
var1:  123455555555 (when the salesrevenue exceeds 10 (breakpoint1), the variable stays constant)
var2:  000000006789 (when the sales revenue exceeds 25(for breakpoint2), the variable is increasing, before 25 it is 0)

```
df = data.frame (
ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
sales = c(1,4,10,12,20,26,28,2,5,9,12,13,18,26,29,35),
var1 = c(1,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4),
var2 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3))
```

My Multi-Level Model has the form:

Y= b0i + b1i*a1ti + b2i*a2ti + eti

(sorry, I m not allow to post images and formulas :( )

a1ti and a2ti are my the coded variables (var1 and var2) which specify the pieces.

Level 1: repeated-observation for each individual level
Level 2: between-subjects level

Could maybe somebody explain me where I have to specify the Level 1 and Level 2 in my lmer()-Code and how I will get the two slopes of my two pieces? Do I have to add specifications between my brackets as O + ..., or 1 + ...  to get only the intercept, etc.?

I guess my Code will look something like this:

```
test <- (lmer(sales ~ ID*var1 + (1|var1) + (1|ID), df))
```

or this:

```
test <- (lmer(sales ~ var1 + var2 + (1|var1) + (1|var2), df))
```

Thank you!

Best wishes Alexa

Comment: The `strucchange` and `segmented` packages are two efforts at providing segmented or piecewise regression. You should edit your question to provide R code that is more clear. The meaning of the apostrophes in those digits is unclear, as is the long string of digits which I'm guessing are meant to be vectors.

Comment: How about a simple regression augmented with dummy variables for structural breaks? Also, are you sure that your data is stationary?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I edited my post, and I hope it is now clear what I am looking for. I m working on Hierarchical Linear Growth Models, a Multi Level approach. So I will need to work with the lm4-package.

Comment: @DWin, if the OP needs to incorporate a random effect in the model then I think `strucchange` and `segmented` probably aren't going to do it.  I think @chandler is on the right track, but the OP may not know how to translate the suggestion into a practical solution ... If I get a chance I will try to answer the question, if the edited version is clear to me when I look at it more carefully ...

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully you can follow my informations.

Comment: @BenBolker, I do not remember random or `lme` references being in the question at the time I posted my comment.

Comment: Maybe I can get even clearer with my question: I dont know which variables to take in my lmer-Code. (fixed effect vs. random effect, etc) In this post the orthography is explained pretty good but I still couldnt figure out how to apply it on my data. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2012q4/019347.html